# How to make people cooperate?

Tags: discussion

It's sometimes frustrating that OPs don't bother reacting on well crafted answers with quite a bit of work behind them.

Or state an answer is wrong and when asked to explain in what way, just disappear and never come back.

Or people reverting edits that clearly are an improvement and when asked for a reason don't answer.

While there's an incentive to accept an answer (+2 rep) I'd be in favor of some pressure on people to honor the work others do for them/the community. What do others think about whether and how? Some kind of flagging maybe?

New here in meta, so if this is a silly question...

Comment: Meh. You can't change laziness. Just down vote things, move on...

Comment: @Zizouz212 If I could I'd start with myself :-)

Comment: Not seeing the feature request here... Just "it sucks when people are disrespectful".

Comment: Removed the tag. I saw it in the slight suggestion for some kind of flagging.

Comment: That's the question I hoped to avoid the answer for. --Rep? --Rep after warning? Good news for me: I'm the one who asked the question... :-)

Comment: Wouldn't that be like penalizing people for looking at a question but not answering it or a rep penalty for voting without commenting?

Comment: Try to know yourself first is rule of asking.

Comment: If you want people to cooperate more fully, please look at the DPRK model...(no, I'm not advocating it!)

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental working principle of a volunteer community such as SO is no one is obliged to spend time on anything that doesn't interest them (in volunteer communities, you show respect by respecting others' time). E.g. you can't make anyone accept your answer or reply to your inquiry if they don't think it warrants the action, or their time, or they just have something better to do.

Thus its model shall be designed in such a way that it still works under these conditions. In particular, it shall require as little work (including "cooperation") as possible to get the job done. And SO's job is to provide solutions to practical programming problems to the programming community in general.

SO's model already addresses all your concerns:

- No obligation to accept/upvote. An answer shall be written to be useful for future readers, not just one person. If your answer is really as "well crafted" as you think, others with the same problem will upvote it eventually.

  - In particular, the sole fact that you put much effort into an answer doesn't necessarily means that it's great by SO's standards or appropriate for the question.
- No obligation to reply. Abandoned questions are automatically deleted after some time if they have proven to attract no attention. If a question can't be answered without some missing critical info, it can be flagged for closure (for closed questions, deletion criteria is more strict).
- For questionable review actions, there's this meta where one can seek feedback about whether some action pattern is okay and/or what are the current community standards on it. If the discussion and voting prove there is a problem, moderators will see it (as a highly voted question) and take an appropriate action.